# A robust, actually working ad blocker for Android (without root access)

Tags: android, ad-blocker

There are tons of adblockers for Android, but is there a reliable solution? 
I'm a bit scared about the possibility of an unintended malware download to my device.

The requirements:

- should block the most advertisement banners in the browser
- should optionally work with a mobile internet connection
- must not need root access

Target environment:

- Android 4.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Adblock Plus](https://adblockplus.org/en/android-install) is a great ad blocker for Android. It will work with root, but does not require it. Some of its features are:

- Can block ads over wifi or mobile data. If your device is not rooted, you must follow [these instructions](https://adblockplus.org/blog/adblock-plus-for-android-issues-with-the-latest-jelly-bean-updates#c004571) to block ads with a mobile data connection.
- Works on Android 2.1 and higher
- Blocks a wide variety of ads

Comment: I was about to say the same thing. I'd add that I had to do the same trick with the proxy server setup with a rooted phone with a 3rd party rom

Comment: Since this is just addressing the web browser aspect, you could also use a standard browser like FireFox for Android and install uBlock.